# debugging a struct implementing an increment function

Tags: go, methods

I’m trying to implement an increment function on my struct. I’m not sure why, but it appears that when I call `F.incr()` in main, the fib struct’s parameters appear to remain constant. I think I may have an incorrect idea about what I’m doing in my `incr()` function, though I’m not able to find the right documentation. What am I missing?

```
type fib struct {
    i uint64 
    fa uint64   
    fb uint64 
}

func (F fib) incr(){
    F.i++   
    F.fa, F.fb = F.fa+F.fb, F.fa
}

func main() {
    F := fib{1,1,0}
    var sum uint64 = 0
    for; F.i <= 10; F.incr() {
        k := f(F.i, F.fb, F.fa)
        fmt.Printf("calculating the %vth f(i,F_%v, F_%v): %v\n", F.i, F.i-1, F.i, k)    
—snip-
```

edit: thanks @peterSO, I needed to change incr to
`func (F *fib) incr(){`

Comment: In Go, all arguments are passed by value. Pass a pointer. The documentation is [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec). For example, "the parameters of the call are passed by value to the function" https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls

Comment: The code from the question does not compile, however as @peterSO wrote you need to use reference for *incr()* function. See here -> https://play.golang.org/p/g2iIXFY4y_U

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update your method to increase the value of the variable at the location. Hence, you need to change the `F()` method

```
func (F *fib) incr(){
    F.i++   
    F.fa, F.fb = F.fa+F.fb, F.fa
}
```

The difference being the `*`